# Gnu sed regular expression extension, how to type these two characters?

Tags: sed, regex

This may be a stupid question, but I'm not sure and just want to confirm. Gnu sed has some regular expression extensions that work in both BRE and ERE mode. The following are an excerpt from the sed documentation:

[image]

My question is, how can I type these two characters in the red square? It seems that they are not in the basic ASCII table and when I copy it from the pdf document and paste to some other place, it looks like a two-byte Unicode character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a back quote (**`**) in first red square and single quote (**'**) in second red square. From [regexp extensions (sed, a stream editor) - GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/regexp-extensions.html)

> \`
>
> Matches only at the start of pattern space. This is different from ^ in multi-line mode.
>
> Compare the following two examples:
>
> ```
> $ printf "a\nb\nc\n" | sed 'N;N;s/^/X/gm'
> Xa
> Xb
> Xc
>
> $ printf "a\nb\nc\n" | sed 'N;N;s/\`/X/gm'
> Xa
> b
> c
> ```
>
> \'
>
> Matches only at the end of pattern space. This is different from $ in multi-line mode.

That's generally with <kbd>~</kbd> above <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in main keyboard.

The text on your screenshot looks different may be because of custom fonts.

Comment: The "custom font" is Computer Modern Typewriter (`cmtt`), one of the default fonts used with TeX (and, thus, GNU's pet favorite [Texinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo)). There are tons and tons of documentation typeset with the [Computer Modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern) family; one ought to strive to become acquainted with its old-school appearance.